# After istakhara should we wait for dream or follow our feeling

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices

Till now I use to believe that istakhara is praying Isha prayer and praying the dua and going to sleep but this [post](https://aboutislam.net/reading-islam/finding-peace/remembering-allah/praying-istikhara-how-to-read-the-results/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=a32b787d73ca08056d0dc736ae412de73f790bee-1618789069-0-Abc-zqMcAmOPQD02NB9t3Za5FQb3RhbdjM8hEfjILXQIi3Fp5nZTv1B2iAXOO4XOLxvJ7BDFHMPfpYrOx8-tBCZHXdcZ_h3pvCGiQqPblzNhlqq4RVlnTdLKjZ_vNAoE_L9pNy5XWhpjK5WZKmFNM3ZhBQaAAWbJdiU7Eim4gH_C_TofiW_5u_KqrIlf-QFCDpojxhozLLhQ3tZFE3H32662PvzRGRdexm_bHDxpeVRxvxt74aKYYk6emE4Mx1RM0KPwPDqxt_gZQUfWIFbnKUlnyTHNbYyyB6R8yZWlajSvAspoX4HHbBkiFBzNkVBmhdjuSc0Mc4Eee4eyEUEFMECeDZiuEtgFbF315xh2FUKiUvxZAe221oUcJU5MzTdCpGtcjSBQpBdSde-kHzfJ__yA55bqF5oLAY4dYAEofb7pPUUxw6LUOAmv-x0_krXf0vdvffOpkSq9C1eySGOOnvTLRkKuJrWtFKVQeFGLRzz50vYyj1BjuH1c_4RVz7wOlw) invalidated that theory. The following is from that website

> *Some people mistakenly wait for a dream to give a clear sign as to what decision to make, but this is not true, and often times it never really happens. In fact, dreams may lead you away from what God wants you to do, as Satan might try to deceive you in your dreams.*

I have always heard that you are shown a dream which you have to interpret to find what Allah is trying to tell you, but what is the right way to know what do to after istakhara?

Answer (score 0):

Assalm o Alaikum.
If you see something in your dream, it's good. But if you didn't see anything you can follow your feelings Because feelings after istikhara is from ALLAH.
Jzk